# Does covid significantly increase the chances of losing a baby?

Tags: covid-19, obstetrics

As two late 20s early 30s healthy adults, both vaccinated with two dosages of Moderna more than 6 months ago, we suspect a pregnancy (wanted!). We've heard that being ill with Covid-19 increases the chances of losing the baby.

Is there any foundation for those rumors? It's on early gestiation, late, or both?

We are gathering information to know if we must go full nuclear and isolate ourselves completely during christmas, or if we don't really risk much gathering (only unmasking during meals). We are sure everyone coming is vaccinated.

Are there other even greater risks for the fetus, related to the mother becoming infected with covid-19?

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. It would be inappropriate for anyone to attempt to address your health issues here. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748).

Comment: For future reference, questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research. For example, this would have been a good reference for your question to cite   https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/need-extra-precautions/pregnant-people.html